# Android SQLite tables and datas in an activity

Tags: android, sqlite, gps

I want to make an activity, which displays tables from a database and some datas from the tables itself. The table's names are in this format: gps_year_month_day, and the tables contain GPS latitude, longitude and time data. So i want to list them in an activity with something like date (table name), duration (elapsed time) and length (from lat and lon). How should i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [ListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html), [SimpleCursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html) and maybe also [ViewBinder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder.html). How to use those you will find a lot of examples, e.g. [this one](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/07/android-listview-cursoradapter-sqlite.html) or [this one](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/09/simplecursoradapters-and-listviews/).